# MySQL - JOIN BETWEEN - Range checked for each record (index map: 0x7)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, between

The following query results in "Range checked for each record (index map: 0x7)".
I would expect because there is a lft + rght index it would use this index. I already found on article [Mysql range check instead of index usage on inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254023/mysql-range-check-instead-of-index-usage-on-inner-join) but this table is using its own structure so the exact same column types. I use MySQL 5.7.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.tree;
CREATE TABLE test.tree (
    lft INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    rght INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    INDEX ix_left_right (lft, rght),
    INDEX ix_left (lft),
    INDEX ix_right (rght)
);

EXPLAIN
SELECT X.*
FROM test.tree X
LEFT JOIN test.tree Y ON  X.lft BETWEEN Y.lft AND Y.rght;
```

Result

```
{
    "table": "UnknownTable",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "X",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "index",
            "possible_keys": null,
            "key": "ix_left_right",
            "key_len": "8",
            "ref": null,
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100.00,
            "Extra": "Using index"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "Y",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": "ix_left_right,ix_left,ix_right",
            "key": null,
            "key_len": null,
            "ref": null,
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100.00,
            "Extra": "Range checked for each record (index map: 0x7)"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know what I`m doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not a fan of `BETWEEN` and would probably use `X.lft >= Y.lft AND X.lft <= Y.rght`. Have you tried writing it this way or using it in a `WHERE` to see if there are different results?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but with the same result:Range checked for each record (index map: 0x7)

Comment: MySQL can't use range scans with JOINs (even if its only one field). You can read what "Range checked for each record" means [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, it looks indeed like this isn't supported